# In practice, how would one determine whether to use the assumption unequal or equal variances in a t-test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I am wondering for the purposes of practicality how one determines whether to use a standard Student's t test or Welch's test for two group means. Is it sufficient to take their empirical standard deviation and to compare them? Would the sample sizes also factor in?

Comment: My decision tree is that if I want to do a t-test, I do a Welch test. Aside from simulations where I know the variances are equal (because I programmed it that way), I can’t think of a place I would use the equal-variance t-test.

Comment: I agree with Dave.  The robustness of the Welch test far outweighs the potential loss of power for me.

Comment: On the other hand, if the treatment affects the variances, why would you even entertain the notion of equal means? The equal variances test is more compatible with the hypothesis that the treatment has no effect whatsoever, and by extension, with permutation tests.